# Python Image Shuffle Failure - where have I gone wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, random

I'm trying to scramble all the pixels in an image and my implementation of Knuths shuffle (as well as someone else's) seems to fail. Seems it is working doing each row. I cannot work out why - just can't see it.

Here is what happens:

[image][image]

Which ain't very scrambly! Well, it could be more scrambly, and more scrambly it needs to be.

Here's my code:

```
import Image
from numpy import *

file1 = "lhooq"
file2 = "kandinsky"

def shuffle(ary):
    a=len(ary)
    b=a-1
    for d in range(b,0,-1):
      e=random.randint(0,d)
      ary[d],ary[e]=ary[e],ary[d]
    return ary

for filename in [file1, file2]:
    fid = open(filename+".jpg", 'r')
    im = Image.open(fid)

    data = array(im)

    # turn into array
    shape = data.shape
    data = data.reshape((shape[0]*shape[1],shape[2]))

    # Knuth Shuffle
    data = shuffle(data)

    data = data.reshape(shape)
    imout = Image.fromarray(data)

    imout.show()

    fid.close()
```

Comment: That Mona Lisa seems to have a mustache. Also, in `shuffle`, you're iterating over every single row in the image. Try `reshape`ing the image into a one-dimensional array and then shuffling it.

Comment: IIRC `shape` will be `(height, width, channels)`, so therefore his `reshape` should already flatten it.

Comment: It is LHOOQ by Marcel Duchamp. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L.H.O.O.Q.  The line data = data.reshape((shape[0]*shape[1],shape[2])) should be doing what you say. I want to scramble the pixel locations not their colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ary` is a 2D array, `ary[d]` is a *view* of a that array rather than a copy of the contents.

Therefore, `ary[d],ary[e]=ary[e],ary[d]` is equivalent to the assignment `ary[d] = ary[e]; ary[e] = ary[e]`, since `ary[d]` on the RHS is simply a pointer to the `d`th element of `ary` (as opposed to a copy of the pixel value).

To solve this, you can use *advanced indexing*:

```
ary[[d,e]] = ary[[e,d]]
```